# Wordpress Hacking (Pharma) /wp-includes /wp-content

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

My site works fine, but when I enter /wp-includes and /wp-content and its derivatives, it suddenly redirects to a site that sells medicine. It's called pharma hacking. I tried the solutions written on the internet but I was not successful. Can you help?

- Even though I disconnect from the database, the redirection continues.
- I emptied the .htaccess file but the problem persists.

For example
`sample.com/ No Problem sample.com/title No Problem sample.com/wp-includes Redirecting Problem samples.com/wp-content/themes Redirecting Problem`

Comment: Probably someone installed additional distributed configuration files (".htaccess" files) in those folders. But whatever, that is not of interest. Your setup is vulnerable, there is no realistic way to clean it. Erase the setup, reinstall the environment and replay the database form your latest backup.